# How to find the id of an object elsewhere the show method in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have a controller named Projects. When I click on a button on the show page I execute a method which is in Projects. I want to find the ID of the current Project in this method.
Here is the controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  #add idea from projects/show
  def add_idea

    @data = JSON.parse(params[:data])
    data_splited = @data["get_idea"].split('|')
    @idea = Idea.new
    @idea.title = data_splited[0]
    @idea.description = data_splited[1]
    @idea.nb_of_votes = 0

    project = Project.find(params[:id]) #this doesn't work
  end
```

And this is the coffeescript code corresponding to the button :

```
adding_idea_to_project = -> 
  $("#add_idea").click -> get_idea_title()   

get_idea_title = ->
  title = document.getElementById("title").value
  description = document.getElementById("description").value
  bank_check = document.getElementById("bank")
  if bank_check.checked == true
    data = "{\"get_idea\": \"#{title}|#{description}|#{bank_check}\"}"
  else
    data = "{\"get_idea\": \"#{title}|#{description}\"}"
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "projectss/idea.json",
  data: "data=" + data
  })
  location.reload(true);
```

The routing is correct and is working, I just can't find the ID of the Project in the given method.
Any Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess: You need to provide the ID as part of your AJAX request:

```
 url: "projects/add_idea/#{projectId}.json"
```